# Excel INDEX / MATCH / MATCH across cell range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the formula right to lookup a value and return the cell underneath that cell, but I can't seem to get the code right and a MATCH/MATCH does not seem to do the trick (at least to the best of my knowledge).

Let's suppose my data set looks like this:

```
        Col1   Col2   Col3
      ---------------------
Row 1 | P(A1)  P(A2)  P(A3)
Row 2 | 10.5%  11.5%  12.5%
Row 3 |     
Row 4 | P(B1)  P(B2)  P(B3)
Row 5 | 50.5%  60.6%  70.5%
Row 6 |
Row 7 | P(C1)  P(C2)  P(C3)
Row 8 | 25.2%  34.6%  88.5%
```

Now I have a reference cell, say A1, which can have the value P(C2) and I want to return the corresponding value underneath P(C2), i.e. 34.6% in the cell A2.

I hope I am not being too cryptic and thanks very much in advance for any assistance.

Best
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following...

[image]

F2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=INDEX(A2:C9,SMALL(IF(A2:C9=E2,ROW(A2:C9)-ROW(A2)+1),1)+1,MATCH(E2,INDEX(A2:C9,SMALL(IF(A2:C9=E2,ROW(A2:C9)-ROW(A2)+1),1),0),0))
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much for your prompt assistance.